# Extracting from a very complex JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to get some information out of a very complex JSON file with Python. Below is just one object from the file:

```
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "/Students/news/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Posts(4)", "etag": "W/\"2\"", "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.PostsItem"
}, "Title": "Term 2 Round 2 draws", "Body": "<div class=\"ExternalClass0BC1BCA4D3EE45A4A1F34086034FE827\"><p>\u200bAs there is no Gonzagan this week the following Senior Sport information has been provided here.\r\n\t    </p>\r\n<ul><li><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/Intranet/students/news_resources/2011/Term2/Knox _wet_weather.pdf\">Knox _wet_weather</a> Cancellations, please see <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.twitter.com/SACWetWeather\">twitter page</a> for further news.</li>\r\n<li><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/Intranet/students/news_resources/2011/Term2/2011_Football_round_2.pdf\">2011 Football draw Round 2</a></li>\r\n<li><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/Intranet/students/news_resources/2011/Term2/2011_Rugby_round_2.pdf\">2011 Rugby draw Round 2</a></li></ul>\r\n<p></p></div>", "Category": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "/Students/news/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Posts(4)/Category"
}
}, "Published": "\/Date(1308342960000)\/", "ContentTypeID": "0x0110001F9F7104FDD3054AAB40D8561196E09E", "ApproverComments": null, "Comments": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Posts(4)/Comments"
}
}, "CommentsId": 0, "ApprovalStatus": "0", "Id": 4, "ContentType": "Post", "Modified": "\/Date(1309122092000)\/", "Created": "\/Date(1309120597000)\/", "CreatedBy": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "/Students/news/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Posts(4)/CreatedBy"
}
}, "CreatedById": 1, "ModifiedBy": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "/Students/news/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Posts(4)/ModifiedBy"
}
}, "ModifiedById": 1, "Owshiddenversion": 2, "Version": "1.0", "Path": "/Students/news/Lists/Posts"
},
```

I can't wrap my head around editing this. Converting it to a python dictionary seems to jumble the order of the attributes up, making it impossible for me to find where one object starts and another begins. What's the best way for me to extract just the 'title', 'body' and 'published' keys and values, and how would I do it for multiple objects?

Comment: JSON mappings and Python dictionaries are not ordered. You just access the values by key.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

obj = json.loads(json_input)

for record in obj:
    print obj["title"]
    print obj["body"]
    print obj["published"]
```

Presuming that json_input is the above snippet, in string form, or already read in via a file. Also note, I presumed the above snippet was to be a collection based on your question.

**Update**

Based on the example, you have another layer that was not present in the snippet originally posted.

Change the loop to be:

```
for record in obj["d"]["results"]:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Trying that gave me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Declan/Documents/Script/list.py", line 14, in <module>
    print obj["title"]
KeyError: 'title' .            

Perhaps I should have included more of my JSON file. This is the full file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b404793c4b7b97ae360.

Comment: @user2226825: `for record in obj['d']['results']:`

Comment: @user2226825 that should work. The example file is massive, and I'm unable to load it on my phone right now. I ran it through Json lint and it was valid on my desktop though. Does every record have a title? It might be worth checking or handling an exception if not all records have the fields you expect. Alternatively, try just loading one record in from your file. If that works the code is ok, it's just the data that is the problem. Try the loop as `for record in obj["d"]["results"][:1]:` to see if one record works.

Comment: @Finglas I'm still getting "KeyError: 'Title'" . Perhaps I've missed something incredibly blatant? This is my code at the moment:

`obj = json.loads(r.text)

for record in obj["d"]["results"][:1]:
 print obj['Title']
 print obj["Body"]
 print obj["Published"]`

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me out this evening. I've solved my problem, here's my code:

    obj = json.loads(r.text)
    
    obj = obj["d"]["results"]
    for b in obj:
     print b["Title"] 
     print b["Published"]
     print b["Body"]

This code is dealing with this JSON: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b404793c4b7b97ae360.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your main JSON object is an array of those objects. Here's how I'd print out the information you're after:

```
import json

main_array = json.load('my_json_file.json')

for sub_object in main_array:
    print "Title: {}\nBody: {}\nPublished: {}\n".format(
        sub_object['Title'], sub_object['Body'], sub_object['Published']
    )
```